# How to draw a fake 3D shape from stroke lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, 3d, stroke, path-effects

Want to draw fake shapes from multiple stroke lines like the image below. As far as I know, it can be done by manually dragging the lines, but it's a hard job on complex shapes, and it's slow and not accurate. Wonder if there is a plugin, extension or path effect can do this in a faster way?

Illustrator or Inkscape can be.

[image]

Comment: So, in essence manual shape generation happens in many cases not by pulling control points, but by cutting existing shapes. In this case you just have a buch of circles that you cut with another circle.

Comment: Or ovals and cirlce in tihis case

Comment: This is discussed several times earlier. Illustrator has very limited and Inkscape has none  tools to define wanted 3D forms and put patterns on them. See this . It contains a link to a tool made by a programmer https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142669/3d-like-wavy-lines This is quite the same https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122443/how-to-create-3d-effect-relief-in-lines-adobe-illustrator  This wants a wireframe https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/152274/how-do-i-create-3d-wireframe-lettering. Your example is tricky - it looks 3D from the top.

Comment: @joojaa  got it, in this case it's more accurate to cut shape with multiple circles than to pull control points. Still wondering if there is an automatic way to do this?

Comment: @user287001 I had tried the script tool in the referred link before asking question, it's an easy way to achieve the effect, but as you said the example is tricky, the script tool didn't give me a 3D round top, but a flat top, and its angle looks like 45 degrees looking up, but not overlooking from top vertically.

Comment: the problem is there is not right way to do it. mainly because lines on a ball dont behave that way, neither does the lines on a cloth, or shrinkwrap either. So you need to use your understanding of what you want to achieve to experiment your way into a answer. Here is [my quick 10 minute test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPAzx.png), still needs a bit more depth expansion but its ok for a first try

Comment: As for automatic sure you could adapt [this script](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78676/isometric-bulging-grid/78680#78680) Not sure its any less work than doing it manually with scissors scale and line tool

Comment: @joojaa yep, script is another way to achieve, agree with you that it may cost more work on coding. The script is my last solution, if others fail ;-). Your 10 minutes test is 100% like the example. Thanks your suggestion.

Comment: in a 3D software like Blender that is quite easy, and you can export the result as vector https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114345/blender-freestyle-vertical-lines

Comment: If you apply in Photoshop filter Distort > Spherize to a square image filled by parallel lines you'll get quite the same as your example. But the result is a bitmap and the needed image size is remarkably big,  for ex. 2500 x 2500 pixels. Too low resolution leaves gaps to the lines.

Comment: @Luciano OK, I'll try it later, thanks.

Comment: @user287001 It gives inspiration to achieve the effect in another way. but yes, bitmap and size is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple 3D forms can be made by extruding or revolving 2D curves in Illustrator. Then one can map patterns on the generated surfaces, but there's very little control on how Illustrator wants to place them. Inkscape has not even this.

You can create 3D-looking patterns by blending in Illustrator. Inkscape has "Interpolate" which is quite the same. Then there's the envelope distortion in Illustrator and a drastically limited version of it in Inkscape. With them you can bend clouds of lines or curves. The result may resemble something 3D surface if you are lucky and in addition you have a goal which happens to be possible to be made in that way.

But if you have an already decided "I want it" 3D form which is not an extrusion or revolved surface you generally have no other possibility to present it as a cloud of curves other than drawing every curve manually. Artists have done it hundreds of years, but developing the needed skills takes years (assuming the person has got in birth what the job takes).

3D programs are useful if the program allows and the user knows how to generate the wanted 3D surface. Your half-sphere is simple. Only to generate such line pattern which shows the 3D form also in the straight top view needs some thinking. One possibility is to split a solid with non-parallel planes and then to use the splitting borders as the image.

[image]

The image is just before the splitting. The solid is a half sphere on a plate.

After using the split body function and hiding the splitting planes the top view in wire frame rendering mode looks right - except there's no straight lines in the left and right and there's a circle which should be removed.

[image]

I took the curves into Illustrator, deleted the unwanted parts with the shape builder, inserted a couple of straight vertical lines and changed the stroke width:

[image]

The curved parts are pieces of ellipses. One who knows some elementary geometry could calculate the right ellipses and draw them in 2D from the numeric measures. A talented and well trained draughtsman may see the right ones without any math. But a 3D program gives them with very low effort, as shown above.

If you want to go to 3D software to make something substantially more complex than what's got by applying a 3D geometry creation primitive like extrude, revolve, sweep, loft, cut etc...  you take a new challenge: It's far from trivial to learn to model something complex, say cartoon figures, realistic curved surface vehicles, animals, etc... Creating them from scratch needs same abilities as sculpting.

Comment: I happened to try Fusion 360 weeks before, according to your suggestion and my understanding of Fusion 360 so far, I think this is a low effort way, even for other shapes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jdleung  You find easily Fusion 360 videos where one puts together say a free form lookalike model of a Ferrari or Mustang P-51. The shown movements (there are plenty of them) are not complex, knowing the needed movements is complex. Making something which resembles say a human face is what I call really complex. For ex this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3DTCgGFBuo   And there's no software usage problems, only the knowledge problem "what is the right form" and, of course, training to move one's hands accurately enough after one knows the right form.

Comment: Could you tell me which 3D software you're using? I created the object in Fusion 360, but under a free version, it doesn't allow to export it to vector format.

Comment: It's DesignSpark Mechanical, a free version of CAD program SpaceClaim Engineer. There's also severe limitations (like usually, buy the real thing if you want more), but printing a wireframe view (+no hidden lines ) with Adobe PDF printer generates often a version which is usable in Illustrator. This was one such case. Try the "print wireframe as PDF" trick in Fusion 360. It's possible that there's also a forgotten hole.

Comment: It seems that the hole is fixed on Mac, I'll try it on Windows later. Thanks.

Comment: Final report, Fusion 360 can still print as PDF on Windows, then import PDF into ai or inkscape to edit the paths. It's a great solution, thanks again.